# How to allow a column on phpmyadmin have the same data values?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I made a column called `password` and when `users` try creating an account with similar passwords, I want to  receive `"Duplicate entry for key"` error.

**Duplicate entry 'admin' for key 'password_2**' I do not have a password_2 column, just a column called "password".

I have tried making the password column `unique`, still doing the same thing. Any ideas?

Here is the table schema

```
CREATE TABLE admin (  
    id int(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    email varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
    firstName varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
    lastName varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
    password varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
    DateOfBirth date NOT NULL,  
    Gender char(1) NOT NULL,  
    phoneNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE KEY password_2 (password), 
    UNIQUE KEY email (email), 
    UNIQUE KEY password_3 (password), 
    UNIQUE KEY password_4 (password), 
    UNIQUE KEY password_5 (password), 
    KEY phoneNumber (phoneNumber) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Have you tried making the column *not* unique? And, are you storing passwords in clear?

Comment: Yes i am storing passwords in clear. Would it be better i put it on md5?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be better. You can just Google for e.g. `81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055` and find the original password.

Comment: Using `md5()` with a custom salt will create a safe password hash i.e. `$hash= md5('ThePassword'.'mySalt');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `unique` index from the `password` and rather add it to `users`

> I have tried making the password column unique, still doing the same thing. Any ideas?

this is the reason why you are getting this error message `Duplicate entry for key`

From your schema Remove this lines

```
UNIQUE KEY password_2 (password), 
UNIQUE KEY password_3 (password), 
UNIQUE KEY password_4 (password), 
UNIQUE KEY password_5 (password),
```

your new schema will look like

```
CREATE TABLE admin (  
    id int(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    email varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
    firstName varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
    lastName varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
    password varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
    DateOfBirth date NOT NULL,  
    Gender char(1) NOT NULL,  
    phoneNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE KEY email (email), 
    KEY phoneNumber (phoneNumber) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Yes, I initially tried making it not unique. What do you mean by "add to users"?

Comment: "Duplicate entry 'admin' for key 'password_2'" The password column i made is called "password" i have no column called password_2

Comment: `password_2` is the name of the key `Unique` that is applied to passwrod, can you share the create table scheme hre?

Comment: Its on phpmyadmin, the only way i know is to export the table. Is there a quicker way? Like how do you get the create scheme?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `admin` (
 `id` int(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `email` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `firstName` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `lastName` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `DateOfBirth` date NOT NULL,
 `Gender` char(1) NOT NULL,
 `phoneNumber` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `password_2` (`password`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
 UNIQUE KEY `password_3` (`password`),
 UNIQUE KEY `password_4` (`password`),
 UNIQUE KEY `password_5` (`password`),
 KEY `phoneNumber` (`phoneNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Thank you for taking the time friend, it solved the problem perfectly!